# Determining if value is between two other values in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm currently working on a project that involves using a user-provided charge table to calculate fees.

The table looks like:

```
MaxAmount Fee  
 10.00    1.95
 20.00    2.95
 30.00    3.95
 50.00    4.95
```

As seen in the table above, any MaxAmount up to 10.00 is charged a 1.95 fee.  Any MaxAmount between 10.01 and 20.00 is charge a 2.95 fee, etc.  Finally, any MaxAmount above 50.00 is charged 4.95.

I'm trying to come up with a sql query that will return the correct fee for a given MaxAmount.  However, I'm having trouble doing so.  I've tried something similar to the following (assuming a provided MaxAmt of 23.00):

```
SELECT Fee FROM ChargeTable WHERE 23.00 BETWEEN MaxAmt AND MaxAmt
```

Of course, this doesn't give me the desired result of 3.95.

I'm having trouble adapting SQL's set-based logic to this type of problem.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT min(Fee) FROM Fees WHERE 23<=MaxAmount
```

Have a look here for an example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43f2a/5

Answer (score 1):

If the `MaxAmount` behaves as the table suggests, then you can use:

```
select top 1 fee
from ChargeTable ct
where @Price <= MaxAount
order by MaxAmount desc
```

As you describe it, you really want another row:

```
MaxAmount Fee  
  0.00    1.95
 10.00    1.95
 20.00    2.95
 30.00    3.95
 50.00    4.95
```

Your original table does not have enough values.  When you have 4 break points, you actually need 5 values -- to handle the two extremes.

With this structure, then you can do:

```
select top 1 fee
from ChargeTable ct
where @Price >= MaxAount
order by MaxAmount desc
```